# $A^*$ has the same range with $A$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$,$Y$, and $Z$ with ($Y$ is separable) be a Hilbert space and let $F \in L(X,Z)$ and $G \in L(Y,Z)$ (Bounded linear maps). the following statement hold:
$R(F) \subset R(G)$ if and only if there exists a positive constant $c$ such that:
$\left\| {{F^*}x} \right\| \leqslant c\left\| {{G^*}x} \right\|$.

Now, let $A$ be an operator defined on some Hilbert space $V$, if we knew that $R(A^*)=W$, how to prove by using the previous statement that $R(A)=R(A^*)=W$ ? Thank you.

Comment: The statement is not true. Consider $A = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0}$ with $A^* = \pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0}$.

Comment: I found this lemma in the book : Mathematical Control  Theory :An Introduction (Jerzy Zabczyk ). section 4, theorem :2.2.

Comment: @Gustav are you sure you have stated things exactly as he has?

Comment: @K.Power yes, I guess.

Comment: I took a look at the book you cited. The first statement in your question is indeed the theorem you cited. I didn't find the second statement in the book, and as pointed out the second statement is false.

Comment: @JoeyZou Thank you sir for the answer. I can't understand how he has used theorem 2.2 to prove that $Im(L_T)=Im(Q^{1/2})$? He has just proved that $||L_T^*||=|Q^{1/2}|$.

Comment: It looks like the $Q$ here is self-adjoint; hence it has a self-adjoint square root, denoted by $Q^{1/2}$. So in this case $Q^{1/2} = (Q^{1/2})^*$, and so showing $\|L_T^*\| = \|Q^{1/2}\|$ is the same as showing $\|L_T^*\| = \|(Q^{1/2})^*\|$, thus allowing you to use the theorem.

Comment: @JoeyZou Thanx a lot sir.